# String interpolation in Swift

Tags: string, swift, string-interpolation

A function in swift takes any numeric type in Swift (Int, Double, Float, UInt, etc). 
the function converts the number to a string

the function signature is as follows :

```
func swiftNumbers <T : NumericType> (number : T) -> String {
    //body
}
```

*NumericType* is a custom protocol that has been added to numeric types in Swift.

inside the body of the function, the number should be converted to a string:

I use the following

```
var stringFromNumber = "\(number)"
```

which is not so elegant, PLUS : if the absolute value of the number is strictly inferior to 0.0001 it gives this:

```
"\(0.000099)" //"9.9e-05"
```

or if the number is a big number :

```
"\(999999999999999999.9999)" //"1e+18"
```

is there a way to work around this string interpolation limitation? (without using Objective-C)

**P.S :**

`NumberFormater` doesn't work either

```
import Foundation

let number : NSNumber = 9_999_999_999_999_997

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 20
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 20
formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 40

formatter.string(from: number) // "9999999999999996.000000000000000000000000"

let stringFromNumber = String(format: "%20.20f", number) // "0.00000000000000000000"
```

Comment: whenever string interpolation doesn't do it for me, i use the good old NSString and its methods.

Comment: I don't want to use NSString or any objective-C code

Comment: Note that `0.0001` *cannot* be represented exactly as a binary floating point number. You cannot expect the output "0.0001" without specifying some precision (i.e. number of decimals) - which is what NSNumberFormatter does...

Comment: well the NS classes are still there in Swift for a reason, just saying. using them doesn't really mean using Obj C. you could try the apple dev forum

Answer (score 8):

### **Swift String Interpolation**

1)  Adding different types to a string

2)  Means the string is created from a mix of constants, variables, literals or expressions.

Example:

```
let length:Float = 3.14
var breadth = 10
var myString = "Area of a rectangle is length*breadth"
myString = "\(myString) i.e. = \(length)*\(breadth)"
```

Output:

```
3.14
10
Area of a rectangle is length*breadth
Area of a rectangle is length*breadth i.e. = 3.14*10
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the Swift String initializer: `String(format: <#String#>, arguments: <#[CVarArgType]#>)`
For example:
`let stringFromNumber = String(format: "%.2f", number)`

Comment: This doesn't work as expected : `let stringFromNumber = String(format: "%.18f", 99.999)` give as a result : `"99.998999999999995225"`

Comment: That's a result of how floating point numbers work. 99.999 can't be precisely expressed in binary thus it needs to be rounded. See wikipedia for more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

Answer (score 2):

String and Characters conforms to **StringInterpolationProtocol** protocol which provide more power to the strings.

**StringInterpolationProtocol**  - "Represents the contents of a string literal with interpolations while it’s being built up."

**String interpolation** has been around since the earliest days of Swift, but in **Swift 5.0** it’s getting a massive overhaul to make it faster and more powerful.

```
let name = "Ashwinee Dhakde"
print("Hello, I'm \(name)")
```

Using the new string interpolation system in Swift 5.0 we can extend **String.StringInterpolation** to add our own custom interpolations, like this:

```
extension String.StringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation(_ value: Date) {
       let formatter = DateFormatter()
       formatter.dateStyle = .full

       let dateString = formatter.string(from: value)
       appendLiteral(dateString)
    }
}
```

Usage: `print("Today's date is \(Date()).")`

We can even provide user-defined names to use String-Interpolation, let's understand with an example.

```
extension String.StringInterpolation {
    mutating func appendInterpolation(JSON JSONData: Data) {
        guard
            let JSONObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: []),
            let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: JSONObject, options: .prettyPrinted) else {
            appendInterpolation("Invalid JSON data")
            return
        }
        appendInterpolation("\n\(String(decoding: jsonData, as: UTF8.self))")
    }
}


print("The JSON is \(JSON: jsonData)")
```

Whenever we want to provide "JSON" in the string interpolation statement, it will print the `.prettyPrinted`

Isn't it cool!!