# How to show variable value in a dynamic constant in Swift?

Tags: swift, variables, constants

I know my question title is confusing but i'll make my explanation clear. After reading my question please suggest a good title so that it will be helpful to others.

I have a label whose text is determined by JSON from API.

```
text_from_json =  "My name is _ and my age is _"
mylabel.text = text_from_json
```

I have my age as "26" and name as "jack" in two constants within class.

```
let age = 26
let name = "jack"
print("mylabel.text")
//my output should be "My name is Jack and my age is 26"
```

I'm looking for function/method in Swift similar to Python:

```
text_from_json = "My name is {0} and my age is {1}"

print("My name is {0} and my age is {1}".format(name, age))
```

Do we have any function in Swift similar to `.format` in Python?

Comment: I think you might be looking for string interpolation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595542/string-interpolation-in-swift

Comment: @davecom: something more than this -- looking for any predefined function that iOS provided as part of framework(if any) to acheive this..like a function which accepts text_from_json string, character to search, replace characters with another value and return modified string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple in Swift. You need to do the following

```
    let name = "jacK"
    let age = 26
    //var formattedString = "My name is \(name) and ag is \(age)"
    var formattedString = String(format: "My name is %@ and age is %d", name,age)
```

For your specific case you can do

```
let name = "jacK"
let age = 26
let stringFromJSON = "My name is _ and age is _"
var formattedString = stringFromJSON.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "%@")
 formattedString = String(format: formattedString, name,"\(age)")
print(formattedString)
```

The above code works.

Comment: But this doesn't work when the main string is assigned to a variable.

Comment: I have updated the answer. If it does not work for you, please share the error that you are getting.

Comment: You missed the issue. See the question. The string `"My name is ..."` is coming from JSON and is stored in a variable. It's not a hardcoded string.

Comment: @MohammadSadiq:Thanks for the post but I think I can make my question more specific. I have my string value "My name is _ and my age is _" from API1 which i parsed to JSON.  And I have another API2 which has values Jack and 26. I need to merge those two such that it generates output "My name is Jack and my age is 26" -- At: rmaddy: I have an idea but looking for good approach to solve this , pls suggest...I can send my API1 as "My name is {0} and my age is {1}"  -- store this in a variable -- and look for {0} {1} characters in that string variable -- and replace them by name and age variables

Comment: Thats like create a string extension called addVariablesToText(input1, input2) and implementation is to search for specific characters in string and replace them. Otherthan this I'm looking for better approach...I suspect iOS will have some function/library which already does this functionality and Im in search of that