# SwiftUI problem on visualization of int inside a text

Tags: swift, date, swiftui

I'm using Xcode 14 and I have a text that has o show a int value that represent the current year so in my view-model I found the year in that way

```
@Published var selectedYear: Int = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
```

and after I put the variable in the text

```
Text("\(vm.selectedYear)")
```

but in the view it is shown like this : 2,022 instead of 2022 and I don't understand why

it seams only a problem on representation in text because if printed it show 2022

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, works for me:

```
Text(String(vm.selectedYear))
```

See also this post: [String interpolation in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595542/string-interpolation-in-swift)  for how to use custom interpolations

Comment: thanks perfect, strange I had always done in that way and never facing this problem